# PHP Get only a part of the full path

Tags: php, string, path

I would like to know how can I subtract only a part of the full path:

I get the full path of the current folder:

```
$dbc_root = getcwd(); // That will return let's say "/home/USER/public_html/test2"
```

I want to select only "/public_html/test2"

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I think you should check the path related methods:

```
pathinfo() - Returns information about a file path
dirname() - Returns directory name component of path
basename() - Returns filename component of path
```

You should be able to find a solution with one of these.

Comment: This wont work if you have two or more directories above of the `USER` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know what the part of the path you want to discard is, you could simply do a str_replace:

```
$dbc_root = str_replace('/home/USER/', '', $dbc_root);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how fixed the format is. In easiest form:

```
$dbc_root = str_replace('/home/USER', '', getcwd());
```

If you need to get everything after `public_html`:

```
preg_match('/public_html.*$/', getcwd(), $match);
$dbc_root = $match;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function pieces($p, $offset, $length = null)
{
  if ($offset >= 0) $offset++; // to adjust for the leading /
  return implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $p), $offset, $length));
}

echo pieces('/a/b/c/d', 0, 1); // 'a'
echo pieces('/a/b/c/d', 0, 2); // 'a/b'
echo pieces('/a/b/c/d', -2); // 'c/d'
echo pieces('/a/b/c/d', -2, 1); // 'c'
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `/home/USER` with an empty string:

```
$path=str_replace("/home/USER", "", getcwd());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $dbc_root = getcwd(); // That will return let's say "/home/USER/public_html/test2"
    $dbc_root .= str_replace('/home/USER', '', $dbc_root); // Remember to replace USER with the correct username in your file ;-)
```

After this your `$dbc_root` should be without /home/USER

I didn't test, if you prefer to create a new var for this... 
You could try:

```
   $slim_dbc_root = str_replace('/home/USER', '', $dbc_root);
```

I hope this will help you into the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Try this "/home/pophub/public_html/" is the text you are removing from the getcwd()

```
$dir = getcwd();
$dir1 = str_replace('/home/pophub/public_html/', '/', $dir);
echo $dir1;
```